# Flutter : Losing Provider State on Hot Reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I'm using Provider v4.0.0 and when I hot reload the app I lose state from Provider class.
I know provider preserves it's state so obviously my code has some flaw. But I'm unable to find out what's wrong with my code.
Following is my main.dart file :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:scapperapp/provider/auth.dart';
import 'package:scapperapp/screens/authenticated.dart';
import 'package:scapperapp/screens/homepage.dart';
import 'package:scapperapp/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:scapperapp/screens/started.dart';

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => User())],
        child: Consumer<User>(
          builder: (context, User user, _) => MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
              primaryColor: Color(0xFF5B5A92),
              accentColor: Color(0xFFadacdf),
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            ),
            home: user.isAuthorised
                ? HomeScreen()
                : FutureBuilder(
                    future: user.tryAutoLogin(),
                    builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
                        authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting
                            ? HomePage()
                            : HomePage(),
                  ),
            routes: {
              SignupChoice.routeName: (context) => SignupChoice(),
              LoginPage.routeName: (context) => LoginPage(),
              HomeScreen.routeName: (context) => HomeScreen()
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use ```shared_preferences``` package if you want data to be saved after hot reload
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences